# CCSprites and CCButton in wrong spot in iPad Simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I am trying to achieve something like this:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
CGSize size = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size;
[self resizeSprite:background toWidth:size.width toHeight:size.height];
NSLog(@"Screen size: %@",NSStringFromCGSize(size));
background.position = CGPointMake(0 + background.contentSize.width ,size.height - background.contentSize.height);
playButton.position = CGPointMake(size.width/2, size.height/2);
NSLog(@"Button position: %@",NSStringFromCGPoint(playButton.position));
NSLog(@"Background position: %@",NSStringFromCGPoint(background.position));
```

And here is the resizeSprite method:

```
-(void)resizeSprite:(CCSprite*)sprite toWidth:(float)width toHeight:(float)height {
    sprite.scaleX = width / sprite.contentSize.width;
    sprite.scaleY = height / sprite.contentSize.height;
}
```

When I run in the iPhone 4 inch simulator it looks perfect but when I run on the iPad simulator it looks like this:

[image]

If I use:

```
CGSize size = [[CCDirector sharedDirector]viewSize];
```

It looks like this on the iPad:

[image]

Comment: Try replacing "[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size" to: "[[CCDirector sharedDirector]viewSize];"

Comment: It's very strange. Last try is to change: sprite.contentSize.width; to: [sprite boundingBox].size.width and height. And background.position replace contentSize with boundingBox too.

Comment: Anyway, you are positioning the background in a very strange way. If I'm not wrong, you want it centered, so why don't you edit the position to size.width/2 and size.height/2 when it has been scaled?

Comment: @mursang Ya you are right...size.width/2 and size.height/2 worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right Solution:

Changed

```
-(void)resizeSprite:(CCSprite*)sprite toWidth:(float)width toHeight:(float)height {
sprite.scaleX = width / sprite.contentSize.width;
sprite.scaleY = height / sprite.contentSize.height;
}
```

To:

```
-(void)resizeSprite:(CCSprite*)sprite toWidth:(float)width toHeight:(float)height {
sprite.scaleX = width / [sprite boundingBox].size.width;
sprite.scaleY = height / [sprite boundingBox].size.height;
}
```

And change background position to:

```
background.position = CGPointMake(size.width/2, size.height/2);
```